# Are autowired objects in spring-mvc threadsafe?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Question 1) From my understanding spring creates singletons objects, So when I have a controller like below with a autowired service, will that affect threadsafety.

Question 2) If I declare a int type variable at class level and use it in controller or service, will it affect thread safety?

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    public DaoService daoservice;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getBookInfo() {
        Book book = daoservice.getBookbyId(1L);
        System.out.println(book.getTitle());
        return "welcome";
    }
}


@Service
public class DaoService {

    @Autowired
    public BookRepository BookRepo;

    public Book getBookbyId(Long Id) {
        Book book = BookRepo.findOne(Id);
        return book;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thread safety has nothing to do with the fact if something is a singleton or not (or managed by Spring or not). What makes classes not thread safe is shared mutable state. In your sample there is no shared state so this is thread safe. Now if you would share/hold the result of the `findOne` in a class level variable then it would not be thread safe (as multiple threads could concurrently modify the single shared instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q.1 : Are Spring Beans Thread Safe?**
Answer: **No.**

Spring don't give you thread safety for their bean. Spring provide different type of bean scope like *(Prototype,Singleton etc)*. If *Prototype* then a new bean create each time it invoke where a *singleton* bean created for one time and shared in `application context`.

If you are thinking for `HTTP` request, then 2 or more request can come.Hence new instance of a bean is created in each request scope. So you can think they are thread safe in context of `HTTP` request but it's not truly thread safe by spring itself.Because several thread can share the bean within the same `HTTP` request context.

**Q.2 : Are Class variable Thread Safe?**
Answer: **No**
Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419421/4423636)
*All private member variables are shared. They might be final, but that only means that the references can't be changed. Any mutable state must be synchronized.*

Comment: Your Answer ::If you are thinking for HTTP request, then 2 or more request can come.Hence new instance of a bean is created in each request scope.                                                                                                                   Question) for HTTP request you have mentioned if two or more request came, the new instance of a bean is created, Can you explain which bean is it creating here  for every request

Comment: That's the point where I am getting confused,If controller is singleton, How can it be thread safe for every new request

Comment: I already said *but it's not truly thread safe by spring itself*. To be clear, except *singleton* or *prototype* there are some other scope like *request*, *session*. I am saying for request scope. May be my first comment is a bit confusing so. your `@Controller` are in request scope.

Comment: You can further read scope of request bean from spring spec. this will give you a clear idea about scope. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html